# Make in clause to match all items ot any alternative?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, in-clause

I have a table `hotel [hotelid,hotelname,etc]`

and another table `facilities[facilityid,facilityname]`

these 2 tables are linked through table `hotel_to_facilities_map[hotelid,facility_id]`

so the table `hotel_to_facilities_map` might contain values as

```
hotelid facility_id
-------------------
1         3
1         5
1         6
2         6
2         2
2         5
```

now i want to retrieve all the hotels which match ALL facilities asked for

```
select * from hotel_to_facilities_map where facility_id IN (3,5,2)
```

but this will cause the match as an `OR` Expression while i need `AND`.

is there any workaround or solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select hotelid
from hotel_to_facilities_map
where facility_id in (3,5,2)
group by hotelid
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: It worked for me... But i have many columns in `select` so will have to apply all on `group by` so will this affect the query `count(*)` and also i will use these in dynamic search which is a little more big query so will performance be an issue with this??

Comment: Use this query as a derived table or put it in a CTE and join on hotelid to get the other values you need for a hotel.