# how to filter record which contains exactly two values in a table in sql?

Tags: sql

When I use `IN`, it shows all records contains parameter1 or parameter2, but I want it bring to records contains exactly both of them, not just one of them.

If my question is not clear, I can try to explain again.

```
select Hatlar.Name
from HATLAR,
     [HAT-DURAK],
     DURAKLAR
where HATLAR.Hat_Id = [HAT-DURAK].Hat_Id
  and DURAKLAR.Durak_Id = [HAT-DURAK].Durak_Id
  and DURAKLAR.Name IN ('parameter1', 'parameter2')
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make in clause to match all items ot any alternative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430310/make-in-clause-to-match-all-items-ot-any-alternative)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (That is invalid standard SQL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `having count distinct` to make sure both  DURAKLAR.Names are there.

```
select Hatlar.Name
from HATLAR,
     [HAT-DURAK],
     DURAKLAR
where HATLAR.Hat_Id = [HAT-DURAK].Hat_Id
  and DURAKLAR.Durak_Id = [HAT-DURAK].Durak_Id
  and DURAKLAR.Name IN ('parameter1', 'parameter2')
group by Hatlar.Name
having count(distinct DURAKLAR.Name) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

First, learn to use proper `JOIN` syntax.  Commas in the `FROM` clause are soooo 20th century.

Second, you can do what you want with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
Select h.Name
from HATLAR h join
     [HAT-DURAK] hd
     on h.Hat_Id = hd.Hat_Id join
     DURAKLAR d
     on d.Durak_Id = d.Durak_Id
where d.Name IN ('parameter1', 'parameter2')
group by n.Name
having count(d.Name) = 2;
```

Note:  If duplicates can appear in the junction table, then use `count(distinct d.Name)`.

Comment: Thank you dude for advance I know it of course but just  I wrote that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, this should work (assuming the parameters are actually that, and not hard coded strings):

```
select Hatlar.Name
from HATLAR,
     [HAT-DURAK],
     DURAKLAR
where HATLAR.Hat_Id = [HAT-DURAK].Hat_Id
  and DURAKLAR.Durak_Id = [HAT-DURAK].Durak_Id
  and DURAKLAR.Name Like '%' + @parameter1 + '%'
  and DURAKLAR.Name Like '%' + @parameter2 + '%'
```